# Dynamic date in section and TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, datetime

I am trying to dynamically insert a custom date within a section title like so:

(somewhere in preamble):

```
\newdate{prevdate}{14}{01}{2015}
\date{\displaydate{prevdate}}
```

(somewhere in document):

```
\section{Minutes \displaydate{prevdate}}
```

Which works fine inside the document (correctly displays the section title), but in the ToC list, it is printed as "Minutes 0 januari 0".

Anyone any ideas?

A minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage{datetime}

%\newdate{date}{03}{02}{2015}
\newdate{prevdate}{14}{01}{2015}

%\date{\displaydate{date}}
\date{\displaydate{prevdate}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Minutes \displaydate{prevdate}}

\end{document}
```

I really just want to know if it's even possible or that the way LaTeX pages are generated, renders this infeasible or impossible.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\displaydate` is fragile and needs to be `\protect`ed in moving arguments such as section titles.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage{datetime}

%\newdate{date}{03}{02}{2015}
\newdate{prevdate}{14}{01}{2015}

%\date{\displaydate{date}}
\date{\displaydate{prevdate}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Minutes \protect\displaydate{prevdate}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also make `\displaydate` robust (globally) using

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\robustify{\displaydate}
```

in your preamble.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks a lot. Marking as answer!

Comment: @LennartKloppenburg Glad it helped. Thank you.