# Formatted date inside section

Tags: macros, sectioning, isodate

I am trying to compile a document where each section title corresponds to a given date. The date has to be formatted, `2014/01/03` should produce `3rd January 2014` in the title.

I was trying to use the `isodate` package like this:

```
\documentclass[english]{report}

\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{isodate}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\newpage

%Date formatting routines
\dateinputformat{tex}
\origdate

\section{\printdate{2014/01/03}}
  % Some normal lines of text
  \verbatiminput{../20140103.txt}
  \pagebreak

\section{\printdate{2014/01/04}}
  % Some normal lines of text
  \verbatiminput{../20140104.txt}
  \pagebreak

\end{document}
```

but this is reporting errors.

Some details:

- The document will have more than 50 different sections (each with a different date).
- I don't mind using other date formatting packages or options
- I have a script that produces the section blocks from the filename automatically.
- I've tried to escape the `\printdate` with a `protect` but has not worked.

I have read [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/226459/dynamic-date-in-section-and-toc) question. However, I need a lot of different sections each with a different date. I guess there has to be a straightforward way to do this.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What is the error reported?

Comment: It should be `\printdate{2014-01-03}`; if you use `/` as separator, the input should be `dd/mm/yyyy`.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer The error is: `! Undefined control sequence. \su@IfSubStringInString ...}\su@compare #2#1\@nil  l.86 \subsection{\printdate{2014-01-04}}`

Comment: @egreg I've also tested with the dd/mm/yyyy format. Still the same error.

Comment: @mcieec: Yes, I confirm the `@nil` error

Comment: @mcieec Please, complete the code to a minimal (non) working example, starting from `\documentclass` up to `\end{document}`.

Comment: I get no error; the version of `isodate` is `isodate 2010/01/03 v2.30`; I tried with TeX Live 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014 and 2015, without any error.

Comment: @mcieec: After trying your document: There were no errors, but you have to be careful if you use `hyperref` too!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer @egreg Indeed. I simplified too much my example. I am indeed using `hyperref`.

Comment: @mcieec: Do you need bookmarks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'problem' is `hyperref` -- it tries to create bookmarks automatically, writing `pdf string` content to the bookmarks. Apparently `\printdate` does not provide such `pdf string` content. The usage of bookmarks can be prevented with `bookmarks=false` option to `hyperref`.

A working solution, however, not with 'correct' date formatting in the bookmarks, is to use `\texorpdfstring{\printdate{...}}{...}`, where the 2nd argument content goes to the bookmark and the first one is for the section title/ToC.

```
\documentclass[english]{report}

\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{isodate}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\newcommand{\printdatetitle}[1]{%
  \texorpdfstring{\printdate{#1}}{#1}%
}

\makeatletter
%\providecommand{\@nil}
\makeatother

\dateinputformat{tex}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{First}
\section{\printdatetitle{2014/1/3}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @ChristianHupfer! This is enough for my requirements.

Comment: @mcieec: Alright, but I'll try to find a better way, to get the non-pdf-conforming output of `printdate` working

Answer (score 1):

Since you said you don't mind using another package, here's a solution that uses [`datetime2`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/datetime2) instead. This package is a replacement to `datetime` and was designed to provide expandable commands so that the date can be used in bookmarks. Example:

```
\documentclass[english]{report}

\usepackage[en-GB]{datetime2}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\def\iprintdate#1/#2/#3/{\DTMdisplaydate{#1}{#2}{#3}{-1}}
\newcommand*{\printdate}[1]{\iprintdate#1/}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\newpage

\section{\printdate{2014/01/03}}
   Some normal lines of text
  \pagebreak

\section{\printdate{2014/01/04}}
   Some normal lines of text
  \pagebreak

\end{document}
```

The dates appear as "3rd January 2014" and "4th January 2014" in the bookmarks (as well as in the table of contents and the section headings).

If you don't already have them installed, in addition to `datetime2`, you also need to install [`datetime2-english`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/datetime2-english) (for the `en-GB` option) and [`tracklang`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tracklang).